# Woman who gets trained by a soldier; dead soldier returns as a ghost; bird/raven people

Tags: story-identification, magical-creatures

I am writing in hope that someone might be able to recognize a book series that I read some years ago. Can't find anything that resembles my memories of it. From what I recall it contains a strong female lead. In the beginning of the book, she gets training from a soldier, older than her, and they fall in love. The man gets killed and returns later in the story as a ghost.

The female has got magical powers and fights an evil old man, from whom she must escape and travel distant lands. I think she might have had some magical animal with her (a big cat, or something similar) but again, this is very vague in my mind. I recall a character named Sarah, and a man that Sarah used to be together with called Alvar (?), whom the female lead eventually ends up with at the end of the story. I also remember a character of some kind of bird/raven people (maybe she is even called Raven?), who is betraying the lead and her company to the men of the evil old dude. I think there are some problems with her people or something about wings or the ability to fly that makes her do it.

Not very much to go on perhaps, but it someone recognizes anything that might help out I would be most grateful!

Comment: Alvar is an Old Norse name, and it's unusual, to say the least, outside Scandinavia. Since you mention this name, I'm guessing that the story is of Swedish, Danish or Norwegian origin.

Comment: Could it be [Jarastavens Vandring](http://http://fantasyhyllan.se/forfattare/saga-borg/jarastavens-vandring/ondskans-tecken) (the link is unfortunately in Swedish) by Saga Borg? The female lead character is Siri and her man is called Vidar.

Comment: That link turned out broken. [Here is the correct one](http://fantasyhyllan.se/forfattare/saga-borg/jarastavens-vandring/ondskans-tecken)

Answer (score 6):

This sounds more like [The Artefacts of Power](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Artefacts_of_Power)/The Aurian Saga, by Maggie Furey. ([Magikerns Saga](http://fantasyhyllan.se/forfattare/maggie-furey/magikerns-saga/) in swedish)

Female lead character is named Aurian, gets trained by, and falls in love with, a soldier (Forral), the other man who she travels with is Anvar. She fights an evil old man (Miathan) and has a big black panther friend (Shia).
Raven is correct, with wings and bad attitude.